# Make NSTableView cells editable programmatically only

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstableview

How to configure a view-based `NSTableView` to behave like so:

- Rows are selectable
- The user are unable to trigger edit mode by clicking a cell
- Edit mode can be triggered by calling `NSTableView-editColumn:row:withEvent:select:` programmatically

The table view is dragged from the object library of Xcode interface builder, i.e., it uses an `NSTableCellView` (with an `NSImageView` and an `NSTextField` as its subviews) as the table view's cell view.

Comment: What kind of cell view are you using? For example, are your cell views instance of `NSTableCellView` (presumably with subviews)? Or are you using, say, stand-alone `NSTextField`s as your cell views? Or something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For view-based table views, `-editColumn:row:withEvent:select:` is relatively ineffective. It attempts to make the cell view the first responder for the window, but only certain views will accept first responder status. `NSTableCellView` does not, because it is not itself editable.

If you want to programmatically initiate editing in the text field within an `NSTableCellView`, you can do something like:

```
NSTableCellView* cellView = (NSTableCellView*)[tableView viewAtColumn:col row:row makeIfNecessary:YES];
if ([cellView.textField acceptsFirstResponder])
    [cellView.window makeFirstResponder:cellView.textField];
```

To disable the user from starting editing through the UI, I think you will need to set the text field to not be editable. You would make it editable just before you initiate editing programmatically. For example, add a line `cellView.textField.editable = YES;` between the above two lines.

Then, you'll want to set it back to non-editable after editing ends. To do this, you can set the `delegate` of the text field to your controller object and implement `-controlTextDidEndEditing:`. Or, similarly, you can add an observer of the `NSControlTextDidEndEditingNotification` notification from the text field. Either way, when your code is called, you set the text field's `editable` property back to false. (If you don't otherwise have a reference to the text field in question, you can obtain it from the `NSNotification`'s `object` property.)